# Best way to model kitchen cabinet

Tags: modeling

I design kitchens and have done in kitchen specific CAD software for a couple of years.  I’ve never been too happy about the rendered designs (no doubt partly to my skill (or lack of)

I like about the kitchen CAD software is the availability of catalogues for different ranges.

1. If I make my own cabinet models for a particular range can I simply import them into a design?
2. If so, can I have a single type of cabinet (eg a base unit) in one set of x,y,z dimensions and change these dimensions after I import the model into my designs or should I have models for every standard width (most common dimension that varies) that we can offer?

Comment: you can create objects then use the File > Append function, then find the object in the Object folder of the file. I know there are some addons to manage assets, and if I'm not wrong an Asset Management may be implemented in some next version of Blender?

Comment: @moonboots Did you mean this one https://developer.blender.org/T46049?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Now to learn to model the cabinets 